# Using 'contain()' in the AuthComponent array to specify fields

Tags: cakephp, authentication

In CakePHP's documentation I've seen from version 2.2 has been added the configuration key 'contain' for the AuthComponent:

> The core authentication objects support the following configuration keys.
>
> [...]
>
> contain Containable options for when the user record is loaded.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

But I can' understand how it works (there is no example).

This does not work:

```
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate'      => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'contain'   => array('User' => array('id', 'full_name')),
            'fields'    => array('username' => 'email'),
        )
    )
)
```

Neither this:

```
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate'      => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'contain'   => array('id', 'full_name'),
            'fields'    => array('username' => 'email'),
        )
    )
)
```

Suggestions? Someone tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contain()` is used to contain a DIFFERENT model, not the same one Auth is already retrieving (unless you're trying to contain other User's ie their friends or something - but then you'd likely have an alias, and not 'User').

So, an example would be:

```
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate'      => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'contain'   => array('Post'),
            'fields'    => array('username' => 'email'),
        )
    )
)
```

Which would then cause Auth to retreive the user's Posts as well when it retrieves the user's data.

Comment: Damn, I didn't understand this. Thank you.
I was hoping they offered a way to set user's fields you want to save in session and so this is only valid for the associated models.

Comment: @Dave I tried this But still I am getting all associated model records.

Comment: @magento_bee ask a new question, provide your details, and link it.  I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

you were almost there. Just add the "fields" key on your first example, like this :

```
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate'      => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'contain'   => array('User' => array('fields'=>array('id', 'full_name'))),
            'fields'    => array('username' => 'email'),
        )
    )
)
```

NB : while this is syntaxically correct, I do not see why 'User' should contain 'User'... well YMMV