# cakephp Auth - can't get data from associated table via 'contain'

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, authorization

When configuring the Auth-Component of cakephp, I'm having problems using the 'contain'-index [(described here)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)...

What I'm trying to achieve is a rights-based authorization (instead of roles like 'admin','user', etc).
So, staying in the often used blog-example, I have a table 'rights' which might have the fields id and name and contain the entries:

```
1: editOwnPosts
2: editAllPosts
```

These rights are connected to the users as seen below:

```
/*
 * Model/User.php:
 */
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Right' => array(
        'className' => 'Right',
        'joinTable' => 'rights_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'right_id',
    )
);

/*
 * Model/Right.php:
 */

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'rights_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'right_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
    )
);
```

Now for every authorization, I will need the user's rights. So maybe if for example he tries to edit a Post, I'd check if the users's rights array contains the value 'editAllPost'. If yes, my authorization function returns true. Otherwise it checks, if it contains "editOwnPosts" and if the Post is the users' then returns true, otherwise false.

Well, I found what I thought would be a solution in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685754/using-contain-in-the-authcomponent-array-to-specify-fields): To use the 'contain'-Key which has been introduced in cakephp 2.2. So I wrote in AppController.php:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        ...,
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields'    => array('username' => 'mail'),
                'contain'   => array('Right')
            ),
        ),
        'authorize'     => array('Controller')
);
```

And to test if it's doing what I'd like it to, also in AppController.php:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    var_dump($this->Auth->user());
    return true;
}
```

But the var_dump I see on any page then only contains the direct data from the User-model itself, not the associated rights.

Did I just make a minor mistake or did I get the purpose/functionality of the 'contain'-index totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set debug =2 for clean model cache?

Comment: Yes, that was set.
Now it works, I think the problem was, that I hadn't added the containable-Behavior to the Models yet...

Now however, I'm having like the opposite Problem, contain fetching too much... but I'll post another question for that...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. This is due to the fact, that the authenticated user is stored in the session. When you log in our user his/her information are stored within the session.

so, if you want to add an additional contain to your user, you have to ensure to log out all users from your app. after logging in again, the new contained model association is available via $this->Auth->user('ContainModel.fieldname').