# Displaying logged-in data in CakePHP 2.5.1

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have the tables:

- `users` (model `User`) - id, person_id, username, password
- `people` (model `Person`) - id, parent_id (foreign key of the same table), last_name, first_name
- `addresses` (`Address`) - id, person_id, street, city

And, models are :

```
 class User extends AppModel {
       public $actsAs = array('Containable');
       public $belongsTo = array(
            'Person'
        );
  }  

class Person extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Parent' => array(
            'className' => 'Person',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        ),
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'User',
        'Address',
        'Subordinate' => array(
            'className' => 'Person',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        ),
    );
}
class Address extends AppModel{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Person'
    );
}
```

Views in `View/Users/` folder:

```
register.ctp
login.ctp
logout.ctp
profile.ctp
```

After registration and login, I need to show the profile data. For that, I use the following function in`UsersController`:-

```
public function profile() { 
       $this->set('userProfile', $this->Auth->User());

}
```

I have following in `profile.ctp`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Username </th>
       <th>First Name </th>
       <th>Last Name </th>

       <th>street</th>
       <th>house_no</th>

 </tr>

   <?php foreach ($userProfile as $profiledata){ ?> 

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $profiledata['username']; ?> </td>

        <td><?php echo $profiledata['Person']['first_name']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $profiledata['Person']['last_name']; ?> </td>

        <td><?php echo $profiledata['Person']['Address']['street']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $profiledata['Person']['Address']['house_no']; ?> </td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

the auth component in AppController.php

```
 public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session',
    'Flash',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authenticate' => array('Form' => array(
                        'contain'   => array('Person'=>'Address'),
                        'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'))

        )
    );
```

it can retrieve data from users and people tables, but not from address table.

I am getting following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: street [APP\View\Users\profile.ctp, line 32]
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong here? Do I need to create another model for profile (`Profile.php`) for showing profile data?

Comment: When you get an error like 'Cannot use string offset as an array' the quickest way of solving it would be to debug the variable and check what it contains. Using either  `debug($userProfile)` or `print_r($userProfile)` would reveal that the variable's structure is not compatible with your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function

```
$this->Auth->User()
```

does not return an array of models.

Instead, it returns something similar to:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [user_name] => john.doe
    [Person] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Doe
        )
    [Address] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [street] => Piccadilly Street
            [house_no] => 4
        )
)
```

Therefore, you have to remove the `foreach` loop, and access the data by doing the following:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $userProfile['user_name']; ?> </td>

    <td><?php echo $userProfile['Person']['first_name']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $userProfile['Person']['last_name']; ?> </td>

    <td><?php echo $userProfile['Address']['street']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $userProfile['Address']['house_no']; ?> </td>

</tr>
```

Note that there is only one row.

Comment: thank you buddy again ! :) Now, it is showing logged in data for Person, but showing another error: Undefined index: User and Undefined index: Address

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed a typo. You don't need to include the key `'User'`. Regarding `Address`, I believe it's related to `Person` instead of `User`, so it won't be fetched by `AuthComponent`. For this to work, you have to use contain in  `AuthComponent`. You can find an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13685840/3144159). Remember to include `array('Person'=>'Address')`. In your view, you have to use `echo $userProfile['Person']['Address']['house_no']` .

Comment: i included contain in the authcomponent. but it is still showing the same problem. :(

Comment: it retrieves data from users and people tables, but can't show data like street, house_no from address table. showing error: Undefined index: street [APP\View\Users\profile.ctp

Comment: after using echo $userProfile['Person'][0]['Address']['street']; it shows error :Notice (8): Undefined offset: 0 [APP\View\Users\profile.ctp,

Comment: is the auth configuration ok ?

Comment: debugging shows the data from address table. but it is showing error in profile page.

Comment: I think I made a typo. Try `<?php echo $userProfile['Person']['Address'][0]['house_no']; ?>` instead.

Comment: if i want to add another table Email (relation similar to Address), what should i do in authcomponent ? is it like 'contain'   => array('Person'=>'Address', 'Person'=>'Email') ?

Comment: Great! I'm sure you've figured out that the above overwrites index `'Person'`, and that the correct syntax is  `'contain' => array('Person'=>array('Address','Email'))`

Comment: yes, i got it. if you don't mind, i have another issue :) i want to add another relation in contain like 'contain' => array('Person'=>array('Address','Email' => array('Apple'))). and, i have a Apple table with Apple model. to save data of apple table, is it a good idea to use the same controller (UsersController) ? or i should create another controller like ApplesController ? anyway, sorry for naive question :D

Comment: Note that you don't have to add all these relationships to your `AuthComponent` config array. Add only those you want to be fetched at log on. Regarding saving data, it depends on whether you want to save the data all in one go using a single form, or add additional data only once your user has been created. Best practices dictate not to go too many levels deep, as it will increase complexity. Also, you don't want to have ultra long forms, as users will get bored filling them in. It's all a matter of figuring out your workflow.

Comment: i will use another form to add the data for Apple table. it will be after registration and login, a new form will be used to save Apple data and displaying them. these data are associated with the user.

Comment: i used a new controller ApplesController and data can be saved now. but the problem is it does not save foreign key (person_id). person_id column of the apples table remain empty. can you tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: I would need to see some code for the controller, views and models (relationship part). Perhaps you can create another question.

Comment: I have posted my codes in a new question, can zou help please ? :)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791264/showing-associated-data-in-cakephp-2-5-1-for-a-web-application